# why concat to add to immutable array not working?

Tags: javascript

Using immutable array and trying to add using concat is not working. I know concat is concatenates two array thats why i passed array.

```
   let animals=['doggy','monkey','cat'];

   let immutanimals=[...animals];

   console.log(animals);

   console.log(immutanimals);

   immutanimals.push('chicken');

   immutanimals.concat(['bird','lion']);

   console.log(immutanimals);

  //////////////output
    [ 'doggy', 'monkey', 'cat' ]
    [ 'doggy', 'monkey', 'cat' ]
    [ 'doggy', 'monkey', 'cat', 'chicken' ]
```

Comment: `immutanimals` is not immutable, you're pushing to it...

Comment: `concat()` doesn't modify the array, it returns a new array.

Answer (score 1):

`concat()` returns a new array, it doesn't modify the given array like `push()` does. So you need to reassign the result.

```
immutanimals = immutanimals.concat(['bird', 'lion'])
```